OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error after Heroku Mini Plan SSL maintenance
After Heroku rolled out their SSL requirements changes to our Redis Mini plan on staging, we started getting the following error:
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=174.129.197.67:28140 state=error: certificate verify failed (self-signed certificate in certificate chain)
This error does not occur on our production Premium Redis plan.
Here's the stack trace:
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:264:in connect_nonblock' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:264:in connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:306:in connect' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:385:in establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:115:in block in connect' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:344:in with_reconnect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:114:in connect' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/prepend.rb:25:in block in connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/instrumentation.rb:12:in block in connect_with_tracing' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/instrumentation.rb:52:in block in with_tracing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/tracer.rb:357:in capture_segment_error' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/instrumentation.rb:52:in with_tracing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/instrumentation.rb:12:in connect_with_tracing' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/prepend.rb:25:in connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:409:in ensure_connected' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:269:in block in process'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:356:in logging' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:268:in process'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/client.rb:161:in call' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/prepend.rb:17:in block in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/instrumentation.rb:19:in block in call_with_tracing' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/instrumentation.rb:52:in block in with_tracing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/tracer.rb:357:in capture_segment_error' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/instrumentation.rb:52:in with_tracing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis/instrumentation.rb:19:in call_with_tracing' <truncated 125 additional frames> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in call' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/deflater.rb:44:in call' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:25:in call' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.9/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in call' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.1.3.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb:79:in call' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/rack-cors-2.0.2/lib/rack/cors.rb:102:in call' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:536:in call' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/puma-6.4.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:272:in call' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/puma-6.4.3/lib/puma/request.rb:100:in block in handle_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/puma-6.4.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:378:in with_force_shutdown' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/puma-6.4.3/lib/puma/request.rb:99:in handle_request'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/puma-6.4.3/lib/puma/server.rb:464:in process_client' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/puma-6.4.3/lib/puma/server.rb:245:in block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/puma-6.4.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:155:in block in spawn_thread' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/tracer.rb:434:in block (2 levels) in thread_block_with_current_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/tracer.rb:357:in capture_segment_error' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-9.12.0/lib/new_relic/agent/tracer.rb:433:in block in thread_block_with_current_transaction'

Here's our Sidekiq initializer:
require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }, url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
  config.on(:startup) do
    schedule_file = 'config/job_schedule.yml'
    if File.exist?(schedule_file) && Sidekiq.server? && Rails.env.production?
      Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash! YAML.load_file(schedule_file)
    end
  end
end
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  # https://bryanrite.com/heroku-puma-redis-sidekiq-and-connection-limits/
  config.redis = { size: 3, ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }, url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
end
Redis.exists_returns_integer =  true
# suppresses 'sidekiq arguments must be valid json' errors
Sidekiq.strict_args!(false)

We're tried the solution here: https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/issues/5591, adding the following to the top of the initializer:
Sidekiq.default_configuration.redis = { ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }, url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }

and tried upgrading Sidekiq from 7.3.0 to 7.3.4, but none of those solution resolved the issue.
Has anyone else experienced this issue and have you found a solution?

Resolved this by updating cable.yml with a staging entry configuring redis with { ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }, url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
